# why a javascript event not working on firefox?

Tags: javascript

I have an input type file , once the user click to upload his image , the process
of the upload starts and a little thumbnail of that image is displayed, that's works normal on chrome , with firefox there is an issue , no thumbnail is showing after click to upload , this is the code that I am using to make this process :

```
var input = event.target;

// Instantiate FileReader
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function(){
    TheFileContents = reader.result;
    // Update the output to include the <img> tag with the data URL as the source
    document.getElementById("img").src = TheFileContents;
};

// Produce a data URL (base64 encoded string of the data in the file)
// We are retrieving the first file from the FileList object
reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

<s>In your example, `reader.onload` is not a valid method on `FileReader`.</s>  If you want to add an event on `reader` then add it like [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL):

```js
function previewFile() {
  var preview = document.querySelector('img');
  var file    = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0];
  var reader  = new FileReader();

  reader.addEventListener("load", function () {
    preview.src = reader.result;
  }, false);

  if (file) {
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="file" onchange="previewFile()"><br>
<img src="" height="200" alt="Image preview...">
```

I just checked and this is working on Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

The updated value is given [to onload by an event property](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/FileReader/onload) : `event.target.result`

```
var input = event.target;

// Instantiate FileReader
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function(event){
    var fileContent = event.target.result;
    // Update the output to include the <img> tag with the data URL as the source
    document.getElementById("img").src = fileContent;
};

// Produce a data URL (base64 encoded string of the data in the file)
// We are retrieving the first file from the FileList object
reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
```